# append value to an input field in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input type="tel"` with `id="#enter"` and I want to add append values from button clicks. I have done this:

```
$("#one").click(function () {
    $("#myInput").val("1");
});
$("#two").click(function () {
    $("#myInput").val("2");
});
```

So every time a button is pressed from #id 1-9 it enters the corresponding numeric value.

However this doesn't append the value in the input field type just replaces the existing value with the value of the button clicked. How can it append the values?

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R9xL/1/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use something like this to append values:

```
$("#myInput").val(function() {
    return this.value + '1';
});
```

You can also improve your approach by giving each number button a class and register the same event listener for all buttons. For example:

```
$(".dial").click(function () {
    var number = $(this).data('number');
    $("#myInput").val(function() {
        return this.value + number;
    });
});
```

Where the button would be defined as

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs1 dial" data-number="4"> <b>GHI<br>4
```

as so on.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8R9xL/2/

Comment: Thanks that's great and simplified it too. So it knows what number it is by the .dial in class and the value of the data-number?

Comment: Yes, I would say this is most flexible approach.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    $("#myInput").val($("#myInput").val()+"1");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it doesn't append the value, you've done nothing to make it append the value.

To append the value you have to...append the value. Get the current value, add (append) something to it, and then set that.

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    var input = $("#myInput");
    input.val(input.val() + "1");
}); 
$("#two").click(function(){
    var input = $("#myInput")
    input.val(input.val() + "2");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    var input = $("#myInput");
    input.val(parseInt(input.val() + 1));
}); 
$("#two").click(function(){
    var input = $("#myInput")
    input.val(parseInt(input.val() + 2));
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this.

```
$('.pin-number').on('click', (e) => {
  $('#pin').val($('#pin').val() + e.target.innerText)
})
```

Where .pin-number is a set of divs containing a number from 0 to 9 (this is the reason that I use e.target.innerText instead of e.target.value), and #pin is the input where the values are inserted.

Hope this helps!