# Append value to an input field in JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a simple math quiz application for a child with on screen number keys that will append to an input field for the answer. I want to use jQuery event listener linked to a class so I do not have to call an onClick function for each number. I found this question elsewhere but I am unable to comment to further ask issue I am having as I have just joined stacked overflow and it states my reputation isn't high enough.

Link to other question: [append value to an input field in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099216/append-value-to-an-input-field-in-jquery)

When I attempt to append I get an undefined when I attempt to click my buttons and I cannot see where the error in my code is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My jQuery:

```
$(".userIn").click(function() {
  var usrIn = $(this).data('usrIn');
  $("#answer").val(function() {
    return this.value + usrIn;
  });
});
```

Sample of my buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block userIn" data-number="0" id="zero">0</button>
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kreth1127/969r1gp0/3/) with all my linked style sheets and external js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `var usrIn = $(this).data('usrIn');` to `var usrIn = $(this).attr('data-number');`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/969r1gp0/4/

Comment: Thank you so much. Once I moved my function to the document.ready section of my js it began working in the browser as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your data attribute is called `data-number`, not `data-userin`, so you should write:

```
var usrIn = $(this).data('number')
```

But as the text of the buttons really is what you want to add, you could do without the data attributes all together, and just do:

```
var usrIn = $(this).text();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this out and it still wasn't working in my code till I realized that it wasn't working the browser yet it was working in fiddle. Once I moved it into my $(document).ready section it began working. I will be using the other solution which I marked as answered but want to thank you as I tested both your solutions and they worked for me as well.

Comment: NB: jsfiddle does this automatically (putting the script in a load function). It is a setting that you can change, but is like that by default.

Answer (score 0):

try this both, it's working

```
document.getElementById("input_id").value = you_value;
document.getElementById("input_id").textContent = you_value;
```